# using swig to wrap a big library

Tags: c++, wrapper, swig

i have a rather complicated, templated C++ library,
with hundreds of classes and many thousands line of code.
the only external dependency is boost.
i'd like to access this library from R, python etc.

from what i read, swig seems to be the way to go.
but the tutorial seem to work with a single binary
by writing a corresponding .i file.
now writing a .i file for every one class and file in
the library at hand would take probably weeks, if not
month. for now, this would be not an option.

so my question:

- is there any *practical* tutorial for 'swigging' a large
  preexisting library?
- can swig generate these .i file more or less automatically?
- if not, is there any alternative?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen any great tutorials, but the SWIG documentation is decent.

SWIG does not generate .i files, but has many helpful pre-coded .i files. For example, `windows.i` for Windows type support, `std_vector.i` for std::vector C++ support, etc.

SWIG does process .h files, so you don't have to write wrappers manually for all your classes. A simple .i file like below will do much of the work for you.

```
%module mylib
%{
#include "mylib.h"
%}

%include <windows.i> // If on windows...
%include "mylib.h"
```

If your classes and methods have standard types for parameters and return values it may "just work".  But more complicated types may need additional includes, template instantiations, or hand-written typemaps.

Another alternatives for wrapping C++ libraries is `boost::Python`, but I haven't played with it myself.

Comment: thanks, so i have to try that out and see what needs fixing. i wished for a more principled way.